# CodeIgniter classifieds I need DB sketch

Tags: database, codeigniter

I can't image how to create classifieds structure.
Example I have page for cars ads, and there can be fields year, price, and more.
And I have page for mobile phones where can be fields price, color, display size and so on. For another page can be another fields and I need add them dinamicly, it can bee select field, text input, or maybe checkbox.

So how I can add new fields for filtering ads, where to keep form validation rules?

Can someone please give me a sketch of db that can me explain all this process?

Comment: Do things one at a time, see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Start by sketching simple stuff, like ad title, price etc. Get a paper and list the features you need in a paper, then group them and write the sketch it to paper